# Does anyone have access to the texts or manuscripts of the Parameswara Tantram and the Vadavanaliya Tantram?

Tags: gods, tantra, devi, resource, manuscripts

Paarameshwara tantra ( Contains Unmatta bhairava panchanga)

Vaadavaanaliya Tantra ( Contains Shweta Kaalii panchanga)

Does anyone have access to the texts or manuscripts of these two Tantras?

Is it okay if I keep updating this list by editing the question?

Comment: Is it okay if I keep updating this list by editing the question? --- No, it is not .. but you can post separate questions for separate texts ..

Comment: Okay. Thanks. It will be better to have the name of the text in the heading.

Comment: I have added the texts' names in the title of your question